# iCalendar RSVP in Outlook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, icalendar

I'm working with a Ruby/Rails app that sends out meeting requests to Outlook addresses. The meeting requests also go to some office resources that need to be reserved for these meetings.

I want to be able to notify someone if the resources decline the meeting request, but I can't get a reply from them. When the meeting shows up in Outlook, it says the organizer does not require a response.

Currently, I have the following line in my iCalendar file generation:

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:#{attendee.email}
```

Having looked through many Google results, I am under the impression that this should work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: it is up to the organiser to notify invitees if a meeting is cancelled, like for instance if an mandatory invitee (or in your case a resource) is not available/declined

Comment: Do you mean I need to add something to the ORGANIZER line?

Comment: rather that your application should handle conditions where the ressource is not available and then send an update to the attendees. however looking at your answer it looks like I may have been focusing on the wrong aspect of your question.

Comment: Regardless, your comment got me looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook was not recognizing the RSVP value because of how I had set things up. I was using my email address both for the organizer and for a separate attendee, for testing. Once I used another address for the organizer, it showed up correctly.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa487228(v=exchg.65).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa487358(v=exchg.65).aspx) were helpful Microsoft documents.